# Nginx como proxy inverso a una aplicación en tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, nginx

Estoy intentado configurar **nginx** para que apunte a mi aplicación que corre en un servidor tomcat 9.0.x

He apuntado mi dominio (**www.midomio.com**) a la ip del servidor y puedo acceder a la aplicación correctamente de la siguiente manera:

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/miaplicacion

http://www.midominio.com:8080/miaplicacion

No he configurado nada en el servidor tomcat, simplemente lo cuelgo en la carpeta **/webapps** y listo.

Para nginx lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

En **/etc/nginx/conf.d/** he creado el siguiente fichero: tomcat-proxy.conf con el siguiente contenido:

```
server {
listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  www.midominio.com;
    # root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    root /opt/tomcat/latest/webapps/miaplicacion;


    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location /tomcat/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_pass "http://localhost:8080/miaplicacion";
    }

location / {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:8080/";
    }

error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Como resultado www.midomio.com apunta a la página de tomcat y para acceder a mi aplicación debo ingresar: **www.dominio.com/miaplicacion**

He probado varias opciones en el fichero de configuración pero no consigo que al poner en la url la dirección: **www.midominio.com** vaya directamente a la aplicación desplegada en tomcat.

Alguna sugerencia???
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si tu dominio esta apuntando hacia el servidor de nginx y cuando ingresas a **www.midominio.com** puedes ver el index por defecto de tu servidor tomcat hasta aqui vas bien.

Ahora bien para poder acceder a tu app directamente desde **www.midominio.com** debes hacer cambios de configuracion en tomcat, debes crear un archivo **index.html** en la ruta **$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT** y redirigir el trafico hacia tu app escribiendo el siguiente codigo dentro del archivo **index.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://www.midominio.com/miaplicacion/">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**PORQUE SUCEDE ESTO?**

El servlet predeterminado de tomcat intenta cargar los archivos index.* en el orden indicado en el archivo **$CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml**

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

De esta manera para anular el inicio de tomcat con el archivo **index.jsp** creamos un archivo **index.html** en **$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT** que contenga una nueva página de inicio estática o una redirección a la página principal de un servlet tal como lo hicimos al comienzo. Este cambio deberia tener efecto automaticamente sin reiniciar el tomcat ni nginx

Comment: Genial. Funciona casi bien (ahora va por el puerto  80), salvo que no apunta al dominio www.midominio.com, sino a www.midominio.com/miaplicacion

Comment: Muy bien, con ese concepto podras resolver tu problema haciendo los cambios que haya lugar en cuanto a puertos y dominios. Suerte!. Recuerda dar voto a favor por la respuesta si fue de tu utilidad. Saludos!

Comment: @davisoski recuerda dar voto por mi respuesta si fue de tu utilidad. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

una configuración sencilla para proxy reverso con el Tomcat o con cualquier otro servidor de aplicaciones, Nginx funciona por el puerto 80

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;

    ## Optimizar Compresion GZIP Nginx
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml 
    application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

     location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/; ## Ip Original
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Comprueba si te funciona si pones en lugar de

```
location / {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:8080/";
}
```

esto:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:8080/miaplicacion";
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, No. Lo he cambiado pero no va. siempre tengo que acceder con el puerto 8080, http://www.midominio.com:8080/miaplicacion